# Story about a scientist turning people into plants

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this children's book over 10 years ago (as a kid) and was super freaked out by it.

From what I can remember, a scientist puts a chemical/solution into a town’s water supply which gradually turns people into fruit/veg. The protagonists see people's skin turning green and fuzzy at school and realise they have to avoid contact with water/fresh food.

At some point they find a missing person in a lab (greenhouse?) who’s been turned into a semi-tomato plant. They end up saving the day by pushing the scientist into a vat of the liquid at a town fete, and he turns into a giant head of broccoli.

Comment: That sounds hillarious!

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.